# React Hook : Objects are not valid as a React child error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting a "Objects are not valid as a React child" error, when I am calling hooks callback function "**setSearchResults**" to set state. The state value is an array having objects but I am not sure why I am getting this error and how to resolve it.

```
function WikiSearch() {
const [searchKeyword, setSearchKeyword] = useState('');
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

function onSearchChangeHandle(event = "") {
    let term = event.target.value;
    setSearchKeyword(term);
    getSearchResult(term);
}

async function getSearchResult(term) {
    const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';
    try {
        const {data} = await axios.get(url, {
            params: {
                action: 'query',
                origin: '*',
                format: 'json',
                list: 'search',
                srsearch: term
            }
            
        });
        
        // search is an array having objects
        setSearchResults(data.query.search);  // => causing error

      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
}
 
const listData = searchResults.map((search ) => {
    return (
        <Fragment key={search.pageid}>
            <div>
                <span>
                    {search.title}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>
                    {search.snippet}
                </span>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
});

return (
    <div>
        <div className="ui form">
            <div className="field">
                <label>Search</label>
                <input className="input" type="text" name="search" value={searchKeyword} onChange={(e) => onSearchChangeHandle(e) }/>
            </div>  
        </div>
        {listData}
     </div>
)
```

}

API response:
[image]

I want to loop over those search results and show data in the list. Probably
**search.title** and **search.snippet**.

Comment: You need to destructure your object for display it in render

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with the object? Turn into html or just display as a text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `JSON.stringify(*your object*)` to turn your array/object into a string, because JS objects cannot be a valid React Child-elements

```js
...
return (
    <div>
        <div className="ui form">
            <div className="field">
                <label>Search</label>
                <input className="input" type="text" name="search" value={searchKeyword} onChange={(e) => onSearchChangeHandle(e) }/>
            </div>  
           {JSON.stringify(searchResults)}
        </div>
        
     </div>
)
...
```

Comment: I do not want to show data as a string, I will be using the map function to loop over array results and display data in the list.

Comment: @Amanjaura — then do that! The error is because you aren't.

Comment: I was doing that but I removed the code to check whether the issue was with the rendering of the list but even when I removed the code(render list)  I was getting the same error. So this issue is not because I was not using the data.